# "Opening directory permission denied `/Users/myname/Documents/'" in Spacemacs on MacBook Air M1

Tags: spacemacs, helm, osx, permissions

I am using Spacemacs and I am getting this error in HELM when I am trying to go in the Documents folder via HELM on my MacBook Air M1 computer:

```
@@@@file-error: Opening directory permission denied `/Users/myname/Documents/'
```

I can open the file via the top bar menu `File > Open File ...`

But not via HELM.

I have tried this fix:

http://xahlee.info/emacs/misc/m1_mac_emacs_error.html

but it's not working.

One thing though, I can't see only this:

[image]

but not this:

[image]

So, perhaps this is an issue?

Any idea how to make the HELM work in Documents folder?

Comment: I confirm that this does happen on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you give Emacs the permissions to access Folders you want. For convenient, I usually give Emacs Full Disk Access. However, sometimes authorization window do not know why can not pop up, you can reset first

```sh
tccutil reset All org.gnu.Emacs
```